# ARM database error: Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource not found

Tags: json, azure

```
    "resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01-preview",
        "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
        "identity": { "type": "SystemAssigned" },
        "condition": "[and(parameters('enableVA'), parameters('useVAManagedIdentity'))]",
        "properties": {
            "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
            "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorPassword')]"
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
                "apiVersion": "2021-02-01-preview",
                "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/', parameters('databaseName'))]",
                "location": "[parameters('serverLocation')]",
                "dependsOn": [ "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]" ],
                "sku": {
                    "name": "GP_S_Gen5_1",
                    "tier": "GeneralPurpose"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
                    "maxSizeBytes": "1073741824"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I've tried to use the nested resource for my DB, and I get the error that is described below. Deployment performed in powershell.

Comment: Give more details of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t concat the server name in the database name property, just use the db name. The server name is implied by the nested definition.

This is a very common template, one which MS has extensive examples of. Here is a copy from the most basic docs example:

```
 "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "databases",
          "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
          "name": "[parameters('sqlDBName')]",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "sku": {
            "name": "Standard",
            "tier": "Standard"
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', concat(parameters('serverName')))]"
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Comment: So now it gives me the following error

5:05:33 PM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'database1' for type 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases' at line '48' and
     | column '55' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater
     | than its resource name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.

Comment: I pasted in an example. You’re over-qualifying child resources. Consider that the hierarchy inherits qualifying paths (such as type) from its parent.